# error while installing qt mobility tool kit

Tags: ubuntu, qt

I am installing qt mobility tool kit 
when  type `make` the following error occurred

> cd systeminfo/ && make -f Makefile  make[2]: Entering directory
>   `/home/tachyons/Desktop/qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.2.0/src/systeminfo'
>   g++ -c -pipe -g -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall
>   -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_SHARED -DQTM_PLUGIN_PATH=\"/home/tachyons/Desktop/qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.2.0/install/plugins\"
>   -DQT_MAKEDLL -DQT_BUILD_SYSINFO_LIB -DQT_NO_NETWORKMANAGER -DQT_NO_UDISKS -DQT_NO_CONNMAN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtCore -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtNetwork -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtGui -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.7.4/include -I../global -I../../build/Debug/QtSystemInfo/moc -o ../../build/Debug/QtSystemInfo/qsystemgeneralinfo.o
>   qsystemgeneralinfo.cpp In file included from
>   linux/qsysteminfo_linux_p.h:61:0,
>                    from qsysteminfocommon_p.h:57,
>                    from qsystemgeneralinfo.cpp:43: linux/qsysteminfo_linux_common_p.h:452:5: error:
>   ‘QUPowerDeviceInterface’ does not name a type make[2]: ***
>   [../../build/Debug/QtSystemInfo/qsystemgeneralinfo.o] Error 1 make[2]:
>   Leaving directory`
>   /home/tachyons/Desktop/qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.2.0/src/systeminfo'
>   make[1]: *** [sub-systeminfo-make_default] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving
>   directory
>   `/home/tachyons/Desktop/qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.2.0/src' make:
>   *** [sub-src-make_default-ordered] Error 2

how to resolve it